# Ruby on rails Unknow attribute when importing csv file to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I'm trying to import a csv file to a ruby on rails app database. I got this error `unknown attribute '2191' for Landslide.` when running `bundle exec rake db:import_csv`. 2191 is the first item on the first row of the csv file.

import_csv.rake

```
require 'csv'
namespace :db do
  task :import_csv => :environment do
    CSV.foreach("Sample_landslides.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
      Landslide.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "landslides", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "total_id"
    t.integer  "year_id"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.integer  "day_number"
    t.string   "continent"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "type"
    t.integer  "admin_level"
    t.float    "lat"
    t.float    "lng"
    t.boolean  "mapped"
    t.float    "spatial_area"
    t.integer  "fatalities"
    t.integer  "injuries"
    t.string   "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "trigger"
  end
```

Comment: can you please paste headers of your csv file.

Comment: What happens if you do `puts row.to_hash`?

Comment: csv header: Total ID Year_ID Date Date Day number Five day number year Continent Country Location Type admin_level newlat newlong mapped spatial area (m^2) Source Fatalities Injuries Trigger Notes Notes Report 1 Source 1 Report 2 Source 2 Report 3 Source 3 Report 4 Source 4

Comment: `NoMethodError: private method `puts' called for Landslide (call 'Landslide.connection' to establish a connection):Class` when I try `puts row.to_hash`

Comment: if you are using row_to hash your csv headers must match with model attributes

Comment: Thanks it works. Anyway I got this error `ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'Rockfall'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrite Landslide.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.` and it is able to fetch data till that row. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: type is restricted word, you can't use it as a column name in ActiveRecord models (unless you're doing STI).

please rename attribute type to something else and your problem will get solved.

Comment: @Tri Nguyen Rename type to landslides_type

Comment: I changed it into `landslide_type` both in the csv file and the database schema. Somehow I still got this error `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'landslide_type' for Landslide.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge if you are using row_to hash your csv headers must match with model attributes.

```
require "csv"

HEADER_MAP = {
  "Total" => :total_id,
}

HEADER_CONVERTER = ->(header) {
  HEADER_MAP.fetch(header, header).to_sym
}

csv = <<END
 Column1,Column2,EXT:MAT:PIDTC
 100,200,300
 400,500,600
END

CSV.new(csv, headers: true, header_converters: HEADER_CONVERTER).each do   |row|
  p row.to_hash
end
```